# Best way to search many strings in huge files at once

Tags: java

I want to search for 10 strings in huge set of files. What would be the best way to do it?

```
1. Using index of each string to be find in file as string
2. Using contains method of string to find the given each string
3. Using split method of string to find the given each string
```

Currently reading the file as string and using `indexOf` of each string.

```
    public static int countMatchesWithIndexOf(String text, String str)
{
    int index = 0, count = 0;
    while (true)
    {
        index = text.indexOf(str, index);
        if (index != -1)
        {
            count ++;
            index += str.length();
        }
        else {
            break;
        }
    }

    return count;
}

    static String readFile(String path)
        throws IOException
{
    byte[] encoded = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(path));
    return new String(encoded, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
}
```

Is there a way to find the occurrences of each string in a file in a better way to do this?

Assume: Keyword to search - "Emp Id: 124", "Emp Name: Raj", "Emp Id:587", "Entity Not Found", "File Not Found", "Exception Occured", "System Error"

Now i want to search each of the string and the number of occurences in each file as well as overall count in huge log files which is in a directory or sub-directories..

Comment: I would use regex instead of `contains` or both combined, this way, you dont need to know the file name and you can extract it right away.

Comment: This would fit better on https://codereview.stackexchange.com. That said, what is your goal? Only checking whether the search string is in the file, or printing where exactly it is? If the search texts cannot be split across lines, you could read the file line by line (easier on memory) and check each line for each search string. If you only want to know whether the term is in the file, exit the loop after the first one you found.

Comment: If you are going to search multiple times in the same file, then it's better to build an inverted index and search in the index instead

Comment: The algorithmically optimal way would be to employ the [Aho-Corasick algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aho%E2%80%93Corasick_algorithm) (or Commentz-Walter) as it is able to look up multiple needles simultaneously. There are some open-source implementations in Java that you can find and try to employ. But it really depends on whether you need such a level of performance, or a simpler approach works for you. Is there anything wrong with the solution you have?

Comment: I have updated the question with an example. Please kindly check and let me know.

Comment: Yep, sounds like a job for a simple linear search that you're doing, or Aho-Corasick.